# homework parsing strings: removing comma from string (java zybooks)

Tags: java, string, parsing

I am trying to get the strings to separate, and WITHOUT the comma.
We haven't learned anything like arrays, this is an intro class.
Everything I find on here just keeps giving me errors or does nothing to my code in zybooks.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ParseStrings {
    public static void main(String[] args) {



    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in); // Input stream for standard input
    Scanner inSS = null;                   // Input string stream
    String lineString = "";                // Holds line of text
    String firstWord = "";                 // First name
    String secondWord = "";                // Last name
    boolean inputDone = false;             // Flag to indicate next iteration


    // Prompt user for input
    System.out.println("Enter input string: ");


    // Grab data as long as "Exit" is not entered
    while (!inputDone) {


        // Entire line into lineString
        lineString = scnr.nextLine();


        inSS = new Scanner(lineString);


        firstWord = inSS.next();

        lineString.split(",");

        // Output parsed values
        if (firstWord.equals("q")) {
            System.out.println("Enter input string: ");

            inputDone = true;
        }
            //This may be where I am messing up??
        else if (lineString.contains(",")) { 

            secondWord = inSS.next();


            System.out.println("First word: " + firstWord);
            System.out.println("Second word: " + secondWord);

            System.out.println();


        } else {

            System.out.println("Error: No comma in string");
            System.out.println("Enter input string: ");

        }
    }


    return;
    }
}
```

I am messing up somewhere and keep getting different error codes as I keep messing with it...

> "Enter input string: 
>   First word: Jill, 
>   Second word: Allen"

When it should be

> "Enter input string: 
>   First word: Jill 
>   Second word: Allen"

And then also as the computer enters more data I start getting this message:

> "Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException"
>   at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862) 
>   at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1371) 
>   at ParseStrings.main(ParseStrings.java:44)"

Comment: You haven't learned about arrays, but `lineString.split(",")` created an array, you just do nothing with it

Comment: Yeah, I tried looking around the site to try to find a solution and it totally didn't work... ha

Answer (score 0):

One of the possibilities (if you didn't learn about arrays) is to use StringBuilder and remove commas or simply loop over input string and if character at let's say index 8 is comma, you do yourString.substring(0,8);, and then print the second word as yourString.substring(10, yourstring.length); I put starting index of 10 in the second substring because you want to skip comma and a space that's separating first and last name. Here is code sample for using nothing but String class, it's methods and for loop:

```
package com.company;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter first name and last name: ");
        String str = in.nextLine();

        int indexOfComma = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            if (str.charAt(i) == ',')
                indexOfComma = i;
        }

        System.out.println("First name is: " + (str.substring(0, indexOfComma)));
        System.out.println("Last name is: " + (str.substring(indexOfComma + 2, str.length())));

    }
 }
```

Or as I see you tried using split() (but since you said you didn't learn arrays yet I posted solution above), you can do it with .split() like this:

```
package com.company;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter first name and last name: ");
        String[] name = in.nextLine().split(", ");

        System.out.println("First name is: " + name[0]);
        System.out.println("Last name is: " + name[1]);

    }
 }
```

Also, here is an example with StringBuilder class:

```
package com.company;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter first name and last name: ");
        StringBuilder name = new StringBuilder(in.nextLine());

        name.deleteCharAt(name.indexOf(","));

        System.out.println("Full name is: " + name);

    }
}
```

Comment: You didn't need to loop to find the comma. Try `indexOf`

Comment: I used index of in another example, I tried to show different variations.

Answer (score 0):

Your error happens when the Scanner reads all the data, such as calling the nextLine method and there's no line... Or next method when you didn't put a space after the comma

By default, the Scanner uses whitespace as a delimiter. If you want to add a comma delimiter before any whitespace, you can try this

```
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
sc.useDelimiter(",?\\s+");
```

Now, `sc.next()` will read only `Hello` from `Hello, World`, and a second call to it should return `World`

Or you can use the array you made

```
String[] words = lineString.split(",");
String first = words[0]:
String second = words[1];
```